# How to hide credentials in Github Repository: Spring Boot and Azure

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, github, github-actions

I have a **Spring Boot Application** which uses **Azure Storage** for several features. Also, I will be deploying it on Azure App Service and also use a SQL database on Azure. I have to upload the code on GitHub. I am not sure how I can hide my **db credentials** and **connection urls** from public access on GitHub. The repository needs to be public. Please help!

Comment: Don't put them in GitHub.  Put them in a credential store of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Set Your User Name & Password to some environmental variables in your system ..
Like

DB_USERNAME="username"

DB_PASSWORD="password"

use System.getProperty to fetch that value and use in your code..

```
String dbUsername = System.getenv("DB_USERNAME");
String dbPassword = System.getenv("DB_PASSWORD");
```

Make sure to set those env variables in Azure App As Well

I'm not aware of Azure App If there is a way to set while deploying. this works

Comment: and add this file to .gitignore so that it doesn't get uploaded to github?